# Como generar una función correcta para envió de formulario en php

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5

Estoy haciendo un sitio de prueba y necesito generar el php del formulario contacto. lo que tengo armado es lo siguiente.

```js
<?php

// Email address verification
function isEmail($email) {
 return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

if($_POST) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the message
    $emailTo = 'info@bric.com.ar';

    $clientEmail = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
    $subject = addslashes(trim($_POST['subject']));
    $empresa = addslashes(trim($_POST['empresa']));
    $telefono = addslashes(trim($_POST['telefono']));
    $message = addslashes(trim($_POST['message']));

    $array = array('emailMessage' => '', 'telefonoMessage' => '', 'empresaMessage' => '', 'subjectMessage' => '', 'messageMessage' => '');

    if(!isEmail($clientEmail)) {
        $array['emailMessage'] = 'Invalid email!';
    }
    if(!isEmail($empresa)) {
        $array['empresaMessage'] = 'Invalid email!';
    } 
    if(!isEmail($telefono)) {
        $array['telefonoMessage'] = 'Invalid email!';
    }        
    if($subject == '') {
        $array['subjectMessage'] = 'Empty subject!';
    }
    if($message == '') {
        $array['messageMessage'] = 'Empty message!';
    }
    if(isEmail($clientEmail) && $subject != '' && $message != '') {
        // Send email
  $headers = "From: " . $clientEmail . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail;
  mail($emailTo, $subject . " (bootstrap contact form)", $message, $headers);
    }

    echo json_encode($array);

}

?>
```

```html
                <form role="form" action="contacto.php" method="post">

                  <input maxlength="100" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" type="text" name="subject" />

                  <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Empresa" type="text" name="empresa"  />

                  <input maxlength="100" required="required" class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="contact-email"/>

                  <input maxlength="100" type="phone" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono" name="telefono"/>

                  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="4" placeholder="Dejanos tu consulta..." ></textarea>

                  <input class="btn" type="submit" name="">
                </form>
```

El problema es que lo probé y me salta un mensaje que dice;

{"emailMessage":"","telefonoMessage":"Invalid email!","empresaMessage":"Invalid email!","subjectMessage":"","messageMessage":""}

Comment: Solo una duda, por que  la condicion del if para email se repite 3 veces ?

Comment: ahh puede ser que sea eso que me funcione mal, en realidad lo copie de otro sitio pero mucho nose sobre php